# Run multiple files consecutively via SLURM with individual timeout

Tags: python, slurm, hpc, sbatch

I have a python script I run on HPC that takes a list of files in a text file and starts multiple SBATCH runs:

```
./launch_job.sh 0_folder_file_list.txt
```

launch_job.sh goes through 0_folder_file_list.txt and starts an SBATCH for each file

```
SAMPLE_LIST=`cut -d "." -f 1 $1`

for SAMPLE in $SAMPLE_LIST
do
  echo "Getting accessions from $SAMPLE"
  sbatch get_acc.slurm $SAMPLE
  #./get_job.slurm $SAMPLE
done
```

get_job.slurm has all of my SBATCH information, module loads, etc. and performs

```
srun --mpi=pmi2 -n 5 python python_script.py ${SAMPLE}.txt
```

I don't want to start all of the jobs at one time, I would like them to run consecutively with a 24-hour maximum run time.  I have already set my SBATCH -t to allow for a maximum time but I only want each job to run for a maximum of 24-hours.  Is there a srun argument I can set that will accomplish this?  Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `--wait` flag with `sbatch`.

> -W, --wait
> Do not exit until the submitted job terminates. The exit code of the sbatch command will be the same as the exit code of the submitted
> job. If the job terminated due to a signal rather than a normal exit,
> the exit code will be set to 1. In the case of a job array, the exit
> code recorded will be the highest value for any task in the job array.

In your case,

```
for SAMPLE in $SAMPLE_LIST
do
  echo "Getting accessions from $SAMPLE"
  sbatch --wait get_acc.slurm $SAMPLE
done
```

So, the next `sbatch` command will only be called after the first `sbatch` finishes (your job ended or time limit reached).

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.  Just so I'm perfectly clear, I can set #SBATCH -t 23:59:59 in my .slurm file to get my 24 hour desired timeout and --wait in my .sh file and the next job won't start until the previous finishes or times out?

Comment: Yes, indeed. :) If it is behaving as you intended, you can accept the answer then :D

Comment: Thank you.  It is working as intended.  Cheers